# Is it true that $f(X)$ is countable implies $f$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces, and $f:X \to Y$. We call $f$ is measurable if and only if $$\forall B \in \mathcal B: f^{-1} (B) \in \mathcal A$$

I would like to ask if $f(X)$ is countable implies $f$ is measurable. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why would it? Unless $\mathcal A=\mathcal P(X)$, take $A\in\mathcal P(X)\setminus\mathcal A$ (i.e. a non-measurable set) and define $f$ to have one value on  $A$ and a different value on $X\setminus A$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a non measurable subset $A$ of $X$ and consider its indicator function $\chi_A$.

Comment: Good stroke (+1) !